# Redis clean up cluster nodes

Tags: redis, redis-cli

I have a Redis cluster with 6 nodes (3 masters,3 slaves).
One of the nodes has been replaced with a new one but the old container is left in the list of nodes:

```
0ab126e86a172a9471a25ff3d2241b2793b87539 :0@0 master,fail,noaddr - 1627299797915 1627299797816 1 disconnected
```

I would like to remove that entry because that container will never come back but when I run:

```
redis-cli --cluster del-node IP:PORT 0ab126e86a172a9471a25ff3d2241b2793b87539
```

I get

```
>>> Removing node 0ab126e86a172a9471a25ff3d2241b2793b87539 from cluster IP:PORT
[ERR] No such node ID 0ab126e86a172a9471a25ff3d2241b2793b87539
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can try with:

```
redis-cli --cluster forget 0ab126e86a172a9471a25ff3d2241b2793b87539
```

Then run a `soft reset` to update all the other nodes, in the cluster.

Comment: I can run a cluster forget on all the nodes and that is going to work. 
However, I've noticed that del-node does not work if you have some nodes in a failure state because redis-cli tries to talk to disconnected nodes. I raised a bug in redis-cli to fix that behaviour (https://github.com/redis/redis/issues/9957)